# Subracting from two columns of a three column matrix in octave

Tags: matrix, octave

testvar was initially a 47x3 matrix but when i try to subtract 1 from the second and third column using the following command in octave 
`testvar=testvar(:,[2 3])-1` 
testvar becomes a 47x2 matrix. What am i doing wrong.
i want testvar to remain a 47x3 matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting `testvar` with the subtracted result of 2nd and 3rd column. You want to store the result of 2nd and 3rd column after subtraction in 2nd and 3rd column respectively. Hence you should be doing:

```
testvar(:, [2 3]) = testvar(:, [2 3]) - 1;
```